# Do we have $|BA|=B|A|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators, functional-calculus

Let $B$ be an unbounded positive operator and $A$ be a bounded operator on a Hilbert space. Moreover, every spectral projection of $B$ commutes with $A$.
Do we have $|BA|=B|A|$?

Comment: @StellaBiderman  The problem is that I am not familiar with unbounded operator.

Comment: Isn't $|BA|$ a real number and $B|A|$ an operator? How should they be equal?

Comment: @Wauzl  |A| is the absolute value of A, which is also an operator

Comment: You need some kind of lattice structure to talk about positive operators. What space are you considering?

Comment: @Jason That is the problem, the space is not clear....That is all I have.